# How can I create a tie or slur that goes to nothing in MuseScore 3 (let ring notation)?

Tags: notation, musescore, pizzicato

I am transcribing the string bass part from a piece we are playing in Concert Band. It has numerous "let ring" notes, pizzicato with ties or slurs going to open space.

How can I do this in MuseScore 3?
(I have the latest version as of yesterday, OS: Windows 10 (10.0), Arch.: x86_64, MuseScore version (64-bit): 3.6.2.548021803, revision: github-musescore-musescore-3224f34), and I've searched the handbook and site.

The basic problem is that MuseScore wants a target for the end of slurs and ties, so even providing a temporary target doesn't work: the arch goes away with the target being deleted. While I can imagine a solution involving multiple voices, making notes or other elements not visible, I would prefer something that works in one voice, so I don't have to spend the rest of my life maintaining this one score.

Comment: I have the same issue. I raised a "Suggestion" in the issue tracker of MuseScore: https://musescore.org/en/node/332456

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Laissez Vibrer* (let ring) symbol can be found in the articulation palette:
[image: articulation palette with highlighting the Laissez Vibrer symbol]

The default placement of this symbol is directly above/below the note head (which is annoying), but it can be positioned manually without much difficulty (using the mouse).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I never use the l.v. symbol since it's a bit cumbersome. You need to manually position it correctly. This also means that if you do a bit more complicated layout adjustments you'll need to reposition it.

Easier and faster is simply drawing a slur and hiding the end point. No need for multiple voices or whatever.

Edit:

To hide a note, select the note and in the inspector untick the "visible" option. (If it has a stem you need to select it separately and hide that too, but in general I always let l.v. notes end in a whole note, i.e. without a stem)

Comment: I think you still need the multiple voices if you draw the slur into a rest (Musescore will try to skip over the rest by default last time I checked).

Comment: you probably also want to make sure that endpoint note doesn't play (untick that inspector box as well)

Answer (score 1):

If you select your first note and then add a slur, the slur will point to "nothing". Alternatively, you can use a "Let Ring", but this is more guitar-oriented.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My trick is to change the note to two shorter tied notes, hide the second, and disguise the value of the first by changing the head type in Inspector and/or hiding unwanted bits.

[image: screenshot of two variants in MuseScore, the "whole" note and "quarter" note, with invisible parts showing]

The easy way to resize the tie is to click on the right handle and use Ctrl+left.